# How to have stateless code inside a stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to add a checkbox in my app, hence I tried converting the parent to a stateless widget, however, this caused all the formatting of the app to be disrupted. Is there a way to add stateless code inside a stateful widget?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, this might work

```
class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test1State createState() => _Test1State();
}

class _Test1State extends State<Test1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test app',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("THis is stateful"),
        ),
        body: new Test2(),
      ),
    );

  }
}

class Test2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is stateless"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way you can omit the keyword `new`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the parent widget as statefull and make a new stateless widget for your checkbox and form and use it inside your statefull widget by importing it.